# How can I 'sudo watch sensors' and 'sudo docker stats' in one window on Ubuntu Server?

Tags: docker, watch, sensors

I tried

`watch 'sensors | sudo docker stats'`

`sudo 'docker stats | watch sensors'`

`sudo docker stats | sudo watch sensors`

So I assume its not possible to display both outputs in one window? Other than installing something like glances? Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Kindly define "one window" - a split terminal via e.g. `tmux` would suffice in this case.

Comment: I don't know what the output of these look like, but maybe `sudo watch 'sensors ; docker stats'` might work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `watch` command takes a `sh` command line as its argument. So you can simply stack the two commands:

```
sudo watch 'sensors; echo; docker stats'
```

Remember to quote the command so that it's passed to `watch` as a single entity